# MQTT TLS session resumption in C

Tags: c, ssl, mqtt, tls1.2, paho

I'm using the Eclipse Paho MQTT C client to connect to a mosquitto broker with TLS using openssl. This is part of my code:

```
MQTTClient client;
MQTTClient_connectOptions conn_opts = MQTTClient_connectOptions_initializer;
MQTTClient_message pubmsg = MQTTClient_message_initializer;
MQTTClient_SSLOptions sslOptions = MQTTClient_SSLOptions_initializer;
MQTTClient_deliveryToken token;

int rc;

MQTTClient_create(&client, ADDRESS, CLIENTID,
    MQTTCLIENT_PERSISTENCE_NONE, NULL);

conn_opts.keepAliveInterval = 20;
conn_opts.cleansession = 1;

/* TLS */
sslOptions.enableServerCertAuth = 0;
sslOptions.trustStore = "ca_rsp.crt";
conn_opts.ssl = &sslOptions;


if ((rc = MQTTClient_connect(client, &conn_opts)) != MQTTCLIENT_SUCCESS)
{
    printf("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Actually every time I reconnect to the broker, the client make a full handshake. I would like to use the TLS session resumption to reduce the overhead. I've search around the web but I haven't found any example of how o implement that in a simple way.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This came up recently on the mosquitto dev mailing list here https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/mosquitto-dev/msg01606.html

The following excerpt seams to imply it may not be possible just yet with the code as it is.

> > How can I use Mosquitto / OpenSSL C API to leverage session tickets in an
> >     MQTT C client ?
>
> Not at the moment, this needs code changes that are a bit more
>   involved - it looks like we need to use SSL_set_session() to apply a
>   saved session to your client and SSL_CTX_sess_set_new_cb() to save the
>   session out.
>
> > Is there any way I could persist session tickets on the clients, so they
> >     would remain valid across reboot ?
>
> With the above changes, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Make conn_opts.cleansession = 0;
Disabling the cleansession flag  in PAHO-client programs enables session resumption.
I have already verified it with wireshark.

**With session Resumption, 1st packet transmission**

[image: 1]

We can see 4 times communication between server and client in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AiA2.png) image and even certificates are transferred.

**With session Resumption ,screenshot taken for 2nd packet transmission**

[image: 2]
Observe both images carefully , there is only 3 times communication between server and client in[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEnZ5.png) image, hence the server negotiates not to perform full handshake.

Session resumption time limit is *7200 seconds*.

But setting the cleansession flag to 1 will always perform full handshake which means no session resumption.

Comment: The MQTT Clean session flag has nothing to do with TLS sessions, it is all about how QOS1/2 subscriptions are handled while the client is disconnected

Comment: Clean session flag of PAHO mqtt client is linked with session resumption apart from QoS.  Just go to file "MQTTClient.c".  Try to find out `m->c->cleansession == 0` if that is true there is a statement , `SSL_get1_session(m->c->net.ssl);` This function helps in session resumption. Which means when clean session flag is set to false (0) , then session is resumed.

Comment: I have also verified it by just commenting the SSL_get1_session(...) , then there is no optimization seen in wireshark.

Comment: These 2 concepts really should have been kept separate. I will have to find the discussion on the Paho mailing list as to why this decision was made as it seems wrong

Comment: I feel it was a good decision taken by PAHO developers who made clean session flag linked with session resumption because mosquitto client  lacks this inbuilt feature of session resumption.

Answer (score 0):

I feel it was a good decision taken by PAHO people who made clean session flag  linked with session resumption because mosquitto client provided in github lacks this inbuilt feature of session resumption.

[Go through the specification of MQTT v3.1.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64tri.png)

Or refer [MQTT specification in their website](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.pdf)